# Slow query after migrating WHERE EXISTS (SUBQUERY) from MySQL 5.7 to MARIADB 10.6

Tags: mysql, mariadb

We want to migrate a LAMP server from MySQL 5.7 to MariaDB 10.6. We cloned the server, installed MariaDB and migrated the database. I was expecting some speed improvements with SQL queries, but my surprise is that our app is slower with the MariaDB. I'm trying to analyze some queries, I expose you a specific case.

We've a query like this: (a) `SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE EXISTS (SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE outer_col=inner_col AND inner_where)`

With MySQL 5.7: 0.1s. With MariaDB 10.6: 10s

I tried to change the query as suggested [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/exists-to-in-optimization/): (b) `.. WHERE outer_col IN (SELECT inner_col FROM .. WHERE inner_where)`

With MySQL 5.7: 0.1s. With MariaDB 10.6: 10s

Finally, I tried to disable the default on materialization optimizer_switch: `SET SESSION optimizer_switch='materialization=off';`

It works! Both queries now lasts 0.1s with MariaDB too.

BUT, why? Is it not supposed to be an improvement, this optimizer? Do you recommend switching it off permanently? I have other alternatives?

I experimented with optimizer **exists_to_in** too. With exists_to_in=off and materialization=on the query 'b' 10s,  query 'a' 0.1s.

Thx

ANALYZE PLAN with MySQL 5.7 (FAST)
[image: ANALYZE PLAN with MySQL 5.7]

ANALYZE PLAN with MariaDB 10.6, materialization=on AND exists_to_in=on (SLOW)
[image: ANALYZE PLAN with MariaDB 10.6, materialization enabled]

ANALYZE PLAN with MariaDB 10.6, materialization=off (FAST!)
[image: ANALYZE PLAN with MariaDB 10.6, materialization disabled]

ANALYZE PLAN with MariaDB 10.6, exists_to_in=off (FAST!)
[image: ANALYZE PLAN with MariaDB 10.6, exists_to_in=off]

CREATE TABLE sumarized with the relevant rows:

```
CREATE TABLE `GT_CalendariProfessional` (
    `CalendariProfessionalID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ProfessionalId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `DataInici` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
    `DataFi` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
    `NecessitatId` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`CalendariProfessionalID`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `ix_professional` (`ProfessionalId`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `ix_necessitat` (`NecessitatId`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `ix_outerjoin_nec_dates` (`NecessitatId`, `DataInici`, `DataFi`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `ix_outerjoin_prof_dates` (`ProfessionalId`, `DataInici`, `DataFi`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `ix_IdIncidencia` (`IdIncidencia`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GT_CalendariProfessional_GNR_Professionals` FOREIGN KEY (`ProfessionalId`) REFERENCES `GIRH_PROD`.`GNR_Professionals` (`ProfessionalID`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_GT_CalendariProfessional_GT_Necessitat` FOREIGN KEY (`NecessitatId`) REFERENCES `GIRH_PROD`.`GT_Necessitat` (`NecessitatID`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=6423951
;
```

`SELECT COUNT(1) FROM GT_CalendariProfessional` => 5413440 rows

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  We can't see what the indexes, datatypes, etc, are.

Comment: Are all of those on 10.6?  If so, what happens on 5.7?  How big are the tables?

Comment: And we need to see the full query.  _There are many possible reasons for what you are seeing._

Comment: Added EXPLAIN for MySQL 5.7. CREATE TABLE for the main table with relevant fields (the real table have 30 fields). The table have >5.000.000 rows.

Comment: Please file a bug report against 10.6 at jira.mariadb.org

Answer (score 0):

When you have both `INDEX(a)` and `INDEX(a,b)`, Drop the former; it distracts the Optimizer from using the latter.  Sometimes this leads to a slow query plan.  (I see 2 cases of such.)

I would need to see the query to judge whether my advice matters in your situation.  (Even then, I may not know for sure.)  In any case, dropping

```
INDEX `ix_professional` (`ProfessionalId`) USING BTREE,
```

would switch the Optimizer's attention to

```
INDEX `ix_outerjoin_prof_dates` (`ProfessionalId`, `DataInici`, `DataFi`) USING BTREE,
```

which will be "as good, maybe better", but "possibly slightly slower".

Comment: But, what if I need the first INDEX because is needed for other queries where I only filter by ProfessionalId? :-(

Comment: @Dimas - Check it out this way:  see which INDEX (via `EXPLAIN`) is used both before and after replacing the 1- column index with the 3 column index.  This should support my contention.  If it fails to support, please provide `EXPLLAINs` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; I'll check for other subtle issues.